# What is the ideal memory_limit to run on dedicated server

Tags: drupal

I have a drupal 7 website migrated to dedicated server. The previous shared hosting I set the memory_limit from 128M to 512M. I realized the higher value I increase the faster website seems to run. Is it alright if I increase memory limit to 2GB on dedicated server? Is it the higher the better ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a few things:

1. How many visitors you are expecting.
2. speed bottleneck (cpu,ram,hhd)

After a certain point, throwing more ram at php won't do anything. It may be better to assign it to apache/nginx and just have **512MB** assigned to php.